# Split multiple similar notepad text files at a point (text string) and merge particular portions into a single file using R

Tags: r

I have data from a weather forecast station that gets stored in separate text files every day. There are two batches of forecast data in each file which have different columns and column widths. I would like to merge the data from different days/files into one. This is essentially a two-step process. First, I need to split the two forecast types as each will be treated differently. Then each group of data needs to be merged with data from the other files and the information from the file name related to each data parcel.

I have read the data in using either read_document from the textreadr library or readLines. I am not sure which is better.

grep appears to be a good function to identify the start of the second batch of data, but I am not sure how to apply it.

I am also not sure once I have achieved the first step, how to go about repeating the process for multiple files. All the files have a similar structure and the file names follow a consistent convention based on the date, e.g. "20140417.txt" which refers to the date 17 April 2014. I would like to bring the date information in this file name and add it as an extra column to all data contained within the file.

Here is the data from one of my files
mydata <- c("BUOYWEATHER.COM Virtual Buoy Forecast", "Location : 34.4S  18.4E", 
            "Model Cycle: 2015 DEC 11 18Z", "Time Zone: GMT + 2 hours", "-------------------------------------------------------------", 
            "SURF    SURF DIR   SEAS  PERIOD   WIND    WND/DIR", "(m )       (deg)   (m )   (sec)   (kts)     (deg)", 
            "-------  --------  -----  ------  -------  -------", "12/11  8pm   1 -  3  WSW 239    2.3    11.1   13 - 18  WNW 297", 
            "12/12  2am   1 -  3  WSW 242    2.3    11.0   17 - 23   NW 311", 
            "12/12  8am   1 -  2  WSW 244    2.3    10.8    5 -  7   SW 223", 
            "12/12  2pm   1 -  2  SSW 192    2.5     8.5   13 - 18   SE 148", 
            "12/12  8pm   1 -  2    S 176    2.5     8.6   16 - 22   SE 132", 
            "12/13  2am   1 -  2    S 171    2.4     8.6   16 - 22  ESE 117", 
            "12/13  8am   1 -  2   SW 227    2.2    10.2   16 - 22  ESE 120", 
            "12/13  2pm   1 -  2   SW 229    2.1    10.0   17 - 24   SE 140", 
            "12/13  8pm   1 -  2   SW 226    2.3     9.8   21 - 28  ESE 118", 
            "12/14  2am   1 -  2   SW 228    2.2     9.7   20 - 27  ESE 118", 
            "12/14  8am   1 -  2   SW 228    1.9     9.5   18 - 25  ESE 110", 
            "12/14  2pm   0 -  1   SE 133    1.9     5.7   19 - 26   SE 133", 
            "12/14  8pm   0 -  1   SE 139    2.2     6.2   21 - 29  ESE 119", 
            "12/15  2am   1 -  2   SW 221    1.7    14.1   12 - 17  ESE 109", 
            "12/15  8am   1 -  2   SW 220    1.6    13.5    6 -  8  SSW 205", 
            "12/15  2pm   1 -  2   SW 223    1.7    12.7   11 - 16  WSW 242", 
            "12/15  8pm   1 -  2   SW 226    1.8    12.2   10 - 14  WSW 259", 
            "12/16  2am   1 -  2   SW 224    2.1    11.8    8 - 11  WSW 258", 
            "12/16  8am   2 -  4   SW 214    3.0    11.6   16 - 22  SSE 159", 
            "12/16  2pm   2 -  5  SSW 207    3.5    13.2   13 - 17   SE 135", 
            "12/16  8pm   2 -  5  SSW 209    3.7    13.3   18 - 24   SE 130", 
            "12/17  2am   3 -  6   SW 210    3.8    15.1   20 - 27  ESE 116", 
            "12/17  8am   2 -  5   SW 213    3.5    14.1   17 - 23  ESE 108", 
            "12/17  2pm   2 -  4   SW 215    3.1    13.3   13 - 18   SE 133", 
            "12/17  8pm   2 -  4   SW 216    2.7    12.7   12 - 16   SE 141", 
            "12/18  2am   1 -  3   SW 219    2.4    12.3   14 - 19   SE 144", 
            "12/18  8am   1 -  3   SW 219    2.1    11.8   15 - 20   SE 147", 
            "12/18  2pm   1 -  2   SW 220    2.0    11.6   12 - 16  SSE 154", 
            "12/18  8pm   1 -  2   SW 219    1.9    11.4   12 - 16   SE 138", 
            "BUOYWEATHER.COM Meteo Forecast", "Location : 34.4S  18.4E", 
            "Time Zone: GMT + 2 hours", "------------------------------------------------------------------------------", 
            "AIR  DEW       WIND     WIND                         PREC", 
            "TEMP TEMP RH%  SPD(MS)  DIR    SLP  LI  CP CLD% PREC TYPE  T-STORMS", 
            "---  ---  --- -------- ------ ---- ---- -- ---- ---- ----- --------", 
            "12/12 2am   20   16  79   8 - 11  NW311  1011  2.9  1  16  0.60  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/12 8am   19   15  78   2 -  3  SW223  1012  0.3  2  37 10.10  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/12 2pm   19   15  76   7 -  9  SE147  1014 -1.2  2   1  5.40  RAIN POSSIBLE", 
            "12/12 8pm   19   14  74   8 - 11  SE133  1015  1.9  0   0  0.10  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/13 2am   19   14  72   8 - 11  ESE117 1015  4.7  0   0  0.10  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/13 8am   19   14  72   8 - 11  ESE120 1015  5.2  0  64  0.10  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/13 2pm   19   14  73   9 - 12  SE140  1014  3.2  0  49  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/13 8pm   19   14  71  10 - 14  ESE119 1014  1.7  0   1  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/14 2am   19   14  75  10 - 13  ESE118 1014  0.1  0  16  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/14 8am   19   14  74   9 - 12  ESE110 1016 -0.1  0  10  0.00       POSSIBLE", 
            "12/14 2pm   20   15  70   9 - 13  SE133  1014  1.4  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/14 8pm   20   15  70  11 - 15  ESE120 1014  4.2  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/15 2am   20   14  71   6 -  8  ESE109 1012  3.8  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/15 8am   20   14  72   3 -  4  SSW205 1012  3.9  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/15 2pm   20   16  76   6 -  8  WSW242 1012  3.5  0  35  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/15 8pm   20   15  74   5 -  7  WSW259 1013  2.3  0  58  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/16 2am   20   16  75   4 -  6  WSW258 1014  1.4  0   0  0.20  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/16 8am   19   15  78   8 - 11  SSE158 1017 -0.2  0  68  3.10  RAIN POSSIBLE", 
            "12/16 2pm   18   13  72   6 -  9  SE136  1018  3.5  0  54  0.60  RAIN UNLIKELY", 
            "12/16 8pm   19   13  71   9 - 12  SE130  1019  6.5  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/17 2am   18   14  74  10 - 14  ESE116 1019  7.7  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/17 8am   18   15  78   9 - 12  ESE108 1018  8.2  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/17 2pm   20   17  79   7 -  9  SE133  1014  5.1  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/17 8pm   21   18  86   6 -  8  SE141  1013  3.3  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/18 2am   21   18  85   7 - 10  SE144  1012  3.6  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/18 8am   20   19  92   7 - 10  SE147  1012  1.7  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/18 2pm   21   18  84   6 -  8  SSE155 1011  1.9  0  35  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/18 8pm   21   18  83   6 -  8  SE139  1012  3.4  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/19 2am   21   17  79   5 -  7  SSE166 1012  5.0  0   0  0.00       UNLIKELY", 
            "12/19 8am   20   16  77   2 -  2  ESE113 1013  5.3  0   1  0.00       UNLIKELY"
)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That data is in a rough format to process here.  Is there anything you can do to better format?  It may increase the odds of you getting help!

Comment: Hi, Thanks! However the main issue in the question is that I am trying to fix the format. It is only available in some incomprehensible file type. I used the dput function after reading it in with read_document and this is what it gave me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write functions to handle the two types of tables separately.  Here's one way you could start on the first batch:

```
library(tidyverse)

first_tbl <- 
tibble(mydata) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(g, "[0-9]+\\/(.*)[0-9]$")) %>% #find only rows that start with date and end with number
  mutate(g = str_replace_all(g, " - ", "-")) %>% #remove empty space from dashes, since we want to split by spaces
  separate(g, into = c("date", "time", LETTERS[1:8]), sep = " ")
```

I just used letters for column name placeholders. Based on the data, I can't tell exactly how the Buoy.com abbreviations align with the columns.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is useful. I received similar advice, but without using tidyverse. The trick is to split the two types of forecasts and handle them separately. I realise the data pasted in a really nasty way, so it was hard to see the two data portions clearly. Will paste the solution I was assisted with here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that I was assisted with by a collaborator

```
fls <- list.files("Buoyweather data/2015/", pattern = ".txt", full.names = T)

flnames <- list.files("Buoyweather data/2015/", pattern = ".txt")
```

Generate database for output

```
forecast1 <- data.frame()
forecast2 <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(flnames)) {
```

Get contents of the file

```
datL <- readLines(fls[i])
```

Pull out rows that start with a number
The number is specified by extracting the month number from the file name

```
datL <- datL[grepl(substr(flnames[i],6,6), datL)] #datL <- datL[grepl("^1", datL)]
```

Each file has 2 tables with different data, but they differ in the number of characters in each row, so we can separate them by working out the number of characters in each row

```
lengths <- as.vector(sapply(datL, FUN = "nchar"))
```

Extract each type
Virtual forecasts

```
dat1 <- datL[which(lengths == lengths[5])] #extract by number of characters. Here I chose the fifth line to skip any heading rows at the top
dat1 <- gsub("  ", " ", dat1, fixed = TRUE) #trim excess whitespace
dat1 <- read.table(text=dat1, header = F) #convert to table
```

Add column specifying date on which prediction was made using the file name

```
dat1$forecast_date <- flnames[i]
```

Meteo forecasts

```
dat2 <- datL[which(lengths == last(lengths))]
dat2 <- gsub("  ","space", dat2, fixed = TRUE) #fill in additional spaces with word space
dat2 <- gsub("spacespacespace"," NA", dat2, fixed = TRUE) #fill in multiple blanks with NA because these represent missing data
dat2 <- gsub("space"," ", dat2, fixed = TRUE) #replace those spaces which were just additional space with a column separator
dat2 <- read.table(text=dat2, header = F)
```

Add column specifying date on which prediction was made using the file name

```
dat2$forecast_date <- flnames[i]
```

Add the information from the latest file to each of the two growing databases

```
forecast1 <- rbind(forecast1, dat1)
forecast2 <- rbind(forecast2, dat2)
```

Loop to the next file

```
i <- i + 1

            }
```

Add column headings for each of the two datasets

```
names(forecast1) <- c("Date", "Time","Surf_low","Sep","Surf_high","Surf_direction",
                  "Surf_degree","Seas_(m)","Period_(s)","Wind_low_kts","Sep",
                  "Wind_high_kts","Wind_direction","Wind_degrees","forecast_date")

names(forecast2) <- c("Date","Time","Air_temp","Dew_temp","Rel_humidity",
                   "Wind_low_ms",  "Sep","Wind_high_ms","Wind_direction","Slp",
                   "LI","CP","CLD%","PREC","PREC TYPE","T-Storms","forecast_date")
```